# Why isn't my threaded python script not much faster?

Tags: python, multithreading

I wanted to speed up a python script I have that iterates over 300 records.  So I figured I'd try to use threading.  My non-thread version takes just under 1 minute to execute.  My threaded version does 1 seconds better.  Here are the pertinent parts of my thread version of the script:

```
... other imports ...
import threading
import concurrent.futures

# global vars
threads = []
check_records = []
default_max_problems = 5
problems_found = 0
lock = threading.Lock()

... some functions ...

def check_host(rec):
    with lock:
        global problems_found
        global max_problems
        if problems_found >= max_problems:
            # I'd prefer to stop all threads and stop new ones from starting, 
            # but I don't know how to do that.
            return

        ... bunch of function calls that do network stuff ...

        check_records.append(rec)
        if not(reachable and dns_ready):
            problems_found += 1
            logging.debug(f"check_host problems_found is {problems_found}.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ... handle command line args ...
    try:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            for ip in get_ips():
                req_rec = find_dns_req_record(ip, dns_record_reqs)
                executor.submit(check_host, req_rec)
```

Why is performance of my threaded script almost the same my non-thread version?

Comment: if you use `multiprocessing`, that probably works better.

Comment: If it's true that the entire body of `check_host()` is in a `with lock:` block. then, of course, you're forcing only one instance to run at a time.

Comment: @TimPeters Good point.  If I move my `with lock` down to where I increment the value of `problems_found` I get far better performance but the script does not stop when `problems_found >= max_problems`.  How can I get the script to stop after `max_problems` has been reached?

Comment: Why are you locking anything here?  I don't see any dangerous operations.

Comment: @RedCricket, that's a different question entirely - and a much harder one to answer. Open a new question for that, or search for the billion times "how do I force threads to stop?" has been asked before ;-)

Comment: @TimRoberts Good point.  I removed the lock stuff but that didn't improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

The kind of work you are performing is important to answer the question. If you are performing many IO-bound tasks (network calls, disk reads, etc.), then using Python's multi-threading should provide a good speed increase, since you can now have multiple threads waiting for multiple IO calls.

However, if you are performing raw computation, then multi-threading wont help you, because of Python's GIL (global interpreter lock), which basically only allows one thread to run at a time. To speed up non IO-bound computation, you will need to use the `multiprocessing` module, and spin up multiple Python processes. One of the disadvantages of multiple processes vs multiple threads is that it is harder to share data/memory between processes (because they have separate address spaces) vs threads (threads share memory because they are part of the same process).

Another thing that is important to consider is how you are using locks. If you put too much code under a lock, then threads won't be able to concurrently execute that code. You should try to have the smallest amount of code possible under any given lock, and only in places where shared data is accessed. If your entire thread function body is under a lock then you eliminate the potential for speed improvement via multi-threading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @vasis my check_host() function does DNS lookup and if that succeeds it checks that certain ports are open on the remote host.